# Launch Userform when Outlook Template is opened

Tags: vba, templates, outlook, userform

I have a User Access Request form that I created in Word, and have now been asked to replicate in an outlook email template. This `.oft` file will be placed on our website, so that when users click on the link, they will download the `.oft` file. When the user opens the file, an email with the User Access Request form in the body will load.

I was able to set up the bookmarks, and import the `Userform` from Word, and have even gotten everything to populate correctly in the email from the `Userform`...however I have hit a wall.

I can only get the `Userform` to appear when I run it from Visual Basic in the Developer tab.

What I am looking to do is have the `Userform` pop up as soon as the template is opened, and only when that specific template is opened by a user (I don't want the `Userform` to open if they are trying to create a new email, or when they open outlook, etc). I have tried adding a module with the Userform.show code, I have tried adding the code below into the UserForm's code as well, with no luck.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can get this to work properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need your custom logic to be present on every user's PC in order for this to work.  Since you have created a UserForm in your Outlook VBA project, you will need to copy that form and supporting macros to every user's Outlook VBA project.

Often it is better to develop a COM Add-in to host your logic, and deploy it using a Windows Installer package.  Deploying the .otm file where the VBA is stored is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to get it to work. I added the following code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
R1AccessRequest.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Worked beautifully... until I sent the template over to a colleague to test... Userform appears to be tied to my outlook, and didn't appear for him. We opened up VB on his laptop, and saw that the form was not present :( From what I have been able to gather online, it doesn't seem possible.